# Hello I can't get this extension to work vs code

Tags: android, visual-studio-code

I can't get the following extension to work on vs code [android-support](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AntonyDalmiere.android-support)

I specify that Java is correctly installed on my computer as well as gradle and android studio

When I run the extension I type in my application name as well as the name for the package except at the end when I press enter I have the following error appearing.

`Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')`

Comment: The extension is not open sourced in its current state, and its author disappeared for more than a year. Do you really want to use it without any serious support?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to first open a folder through the usual vscode menu, then invoke the command palette with `ctrl+shift+p` and look for `android new project`, click on it, provide the data and you should be set.